# Probleme mit deren Tochter

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-case

So here is a sentence I've come across on one of the forums

"Beim Mittagessen erzählte sie ihm alles über die Probleme **mit deren Tochter**."

While I am aware of the fact that the determiner "der" may be used in its Genitive form as a substitute for possessive determiners, I'm still a little confused by this "mit" here. Isn't "der" already placed in the Genitive? Is it acceptable to just smack the Dative case on top? If so, would the following not be considered a double possessive:

"Der Höhepunkt **von deren Leistung**"

Btw, my question does not encompass to whom "deren" is referring to. I'm just curious whether it's possible to apply a second case on top of the already genitive "der". Therefore, I hope adding further context isn't necessary

Comment: I don't see the stacking-on hypothesis as correct representation of what's going on. We simply have *Probleme haben mit* and the desire to additonally qualify *Tochter*. As consequence I don't understand, what is the root concern here.

Comment: So your assumption is *deren* is genitive feminine singular *der* plus dative *-en*?

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence has three possible alternatives:

1. > ... Probleme mit *der* Tochter

   There's no genitive here (but rather a dative caused by "mit"), that is simply a definitive article, but no demonstrative pronoun
2. > ... Probleme mit *ihrer* Tochter

   There's a genitive, but no clearly marked plural (because of the ambiguity of *ihrer* in both singular and plural) here - this sounds as if she was only *her* daughter
3. > ... Probleme mit *deren* Tochter

   Bot genitive and plural are clearly marked and distinguishable. Also the demonstartive pronoun is clearly visible.

And that's probably why this is written as it is.

Your confusion might be caused by the fact that the genitive of the **article** "die" is "der", while the genitive of the **demonstrative pronoun** "die" is "deren" (while in a lot of other forms, demonstrative pronoun and article are identical).

Comment: How is plural marked and distinguishable in "deren"?!

Comment: @wonderbear 'seiner' or 'ihrer' would be singular, only referring to one parent. 'deren' ' makes clear that the conversation happens with both parents

Comment: @planetmaker no it really doesn't; "deren" can be the possessive form of a singular "sie" too, like "dessen" for a singular "er"

Comment: Stimmt, das ist auch möglich

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to add a case on top. While possessive pronouns inflect for case and gender of the following word, "derer / deren" does not.

> Deren Tochter gab deren Sohn deren Pakete. 
> Der Sohn war deren Pakete leid.

There is no dative stacked on top, "deren" is just how the genitive of "die" looks like. The same holds for "dessen".
It's not like "meine Tochter, meiner Tochter" where "mein" marks the case of daughter, but more like "Martins Tochter", where the case is not marked at all.
So "deren Tochter" can actually be all four cases! If genitive can't be marked, Germans tend to use the "von" construction instead:

> die Probleme von deren Tochter.

But this is actually not what the sentence wants to say. "Probleme mit deren Tochter" are problems *with* their daughter, while "Probleme von deren Tochter" are *their daughter's* problems. Problems with their daughter are likely not their daughter's, but rather *their* problems.

Addendum: "deren" and "derer" are two different genitive forms of "die" that can in many cases be used interchangingly, see also [this leo.org article on the difference](https://blog.leo.org/2018/08/24/zwei-woerter-aufgrund-derenderer-manche-ins-zweifeln-geraten/). In front of nouns, "deren" is preferred.

"Der Höhepunkt von deren Leistung" is as much a double possessive as "Der Höhepunkt der Leistung von denen" or "Der Höhepunkt von der Leistung von denen" is.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a slightly different example in all genders and plural.

- Probleme mit dem Wagen des Onkels — Probleme mit dessen Wagen
- Probleme mit dem Wagen der Tante — Probleme mit deren Wagen
- Probleme mit dem Wagen des Büros — Probleme mit dessen Wagen
- Probleme mit dem Wagen der Kollegen — Probleme mit deren Wagen

---

- Probleme mit der Karre des Onkels — Probleme mit dessen Karre
- Probleme mit der Karre der Tante — Probleme mit deren Karre
- Probleme mit der Karre des Büros — Probleme mit dessen Karre
- Probleme mit der Karre der Kollegen — Probleme mit deren Karre

---

- Probleme mit dem Auto des Onkels — Probleme mit dessen Auto
- Probleme mit dem Auto der Tante — Probleme mit deren Auto
- Probleme mit dem Auto des Büros — Probleme mit dessen Auto
- Probleme mit dem Auto der Kollegen — Probleme mit deren Auto

---

- Probleme mit den Autos des Onkels — Probleme mit dessen Autos
- Probleme mit den Autos der Tante — Probleme mit deren Autos
- Probleme mit den Autos des Büros — Probleme mit dessen Autos
- Probleme mit den Autos der Kollegen — Probleme mit deren Autos

As you can easily see, you have to conflate **two** determiners into one each of the time. And that's why there must be both an indication of dative and genitive in dessen/deren.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to say in your last sentence *there must be both an indication of dative and genitive in dessen/deren.* ?

Comment: For example, *deren Wagen* is dative case. It must be because *mit* requires dative. So that -en is, as mysterious as it sounds, a dative ending in this example. It's also a nominative, genitive, accusative ending. It's always -en. Still a dative ending in this example.